# Image of a close set of a continuous function is not necessarily closed

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose a function $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous. What can we say on its image? I thought the image has to be closed, but it seems not true.

Comment: In this case, $f[a,b]$ will be closed and bounded.

Answer (score 1):

A continuous function on a closed and bounded segment attains its minimum and maximum values and each value between them. So the image of this closed segment is again a closed segment whose bounds are the minimum and maximum of this function.

See the [Bolzano's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Theorem).

Comment: @notaprogrammertoday No, it is always a segment of the form $[\min_{[a,b]} f, \max_{[a,b]}f]$.

Comment: Counterexample for your answer: $f(x) = x\sin x$ on the interval $[0,\infty)$, which is closed. You need the set to be bounded. See the other answer.

Comment: Nope, a finite interval $[a,b]$ will be mapped to a closed and bounded set.

Comment: @notaprogrammertoday No. A continuous function on a compact set is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous functions have a property that they map compact sets to compact sets.

That is if $X,Y$ are metric spaces then for any continuous function $f:X\to Y$, the range of $f$ that is the set $f(X)=\{f(x):x\in X  \}$ is compact.

In $\mathbb R$, compact set is equivalent to closed and bounded set. (This follows from Heine-Borel Theorem).

**So coming back to your question**: $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and therefore its range that is the set $f[a,b]=\{f(x):x\in [a,b]\}$ must be compact (equivalently closed and bounded as we are in $\mathbb R$).

So image of your $f$ can't be $\mathbb R,[0,\infty), [0,1)$ or $[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

No. A continuous function maps compact sets to compact sets. To map to sets that are not closed you need a closed set that is not compact; in the case of the real line that means that the set has to be unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

To give the most general answer: it does have to be closed because $[a,b]$ is a compact set, images of compact sets under continuous functions are compact (this is trivial to prove), and [maps from compact to Hausdorff spaces are closed](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/maps+from+compact+spaces+to+Hausdorff+spaces+are+closed+and+proper).